# Can a function receive a tuple with an undertermined number of arguments?

Tags: scala

I have a function that can receive a List[tuple3(foo, bar, fooby)] and I realize I would like to use the same function when using a List[tuple4(foo, bar, fooby, foobar)]. I guess I could use a pattern matching on this but that would make a duplication of code. What should I do ?

```
val tuple3List : List[(Foo, Bar, Fooby)] = List()
val tuple4List : List[(Foo, Bar, Fooby, Foobar)] = List()

myFunc(tuple3List)
myFunc(tuple4List)

def myFunc(tupleList : List[Foo, Bar, Fooby]) = {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it generic by using `Product` but this removes a lot of type information. You can't use overloading because of type erasure issues.

If possible it would be better to use classes rather than tuples and make the 4-element version a subclass of the 3-element version:

```
trait myTrait { val a: Foo, val b: Bar, val c: Fooby }

case class Three(a: Foo, b: Bar, c: Fooby) extends myTrait
case class Four(a: Foo, b: Bar, c: Fooby, d: Foobar) extends myTrait

def myFunc(list: List[myTrait]) = ???
```

If you need to use tuples this can be resolved by using a *typeclass*, but that is quite a heavyweight solution.

Comment: It is indeed an interesting solution, and an object-oriented one which is quite "scala-like". Your idea is probably cleaner that the current accepted answer so I'll change that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

`Tuple3` is a subtype of `Product3`, `Tuple4` is a subtype of `Product4`...

`Product3`, `Product4`... are subtypes of `Product`.

So you can try

```
val tuple3List : List[(Foo, Bar, Fooby)] = List()
val tuple4List : List[(Foo, Bar, Fooby, Foobar)] = List()

myFunc(tuple3List)
myFunc(tuple4List)

def myFunc(tupleList : List[Product]) = {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Also another replacement for "tuple with an undertermined number of arguments" could be [shapeless.HList](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists).

Comment: I have to accept your answer because it answer perfectly the question the way I asked it :)
However, I am not able to retrieve the data inside my tuple.
I mean, I cannot access the tupleList when doing something like println(tupleList._2)) for example

The reason I asked this question is because myFunc only needs the 3 first elements of my tuple so I don't care if there's more, but the compiler abviously forbids me to accept a tuple with a greater num of elements :)

Comment: @BreizhDino Instead of `tupleList._1`, `tupleList._2`... use `tupleList.productElement(0)`, `tupleList.productElement(1)` ...